# How to plan deployment of Google Apps Email and business domain names?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email, domain, google-my-business

I'm currently deploying websites and Google Apps for Business for a parent/umbrella company "UmbrellaCorp" which owns several (ten or so) other subsidiary companies in retail clothing, construction, IT Services etc. All companies are separate legal established companies/entities even though they are under the same parent umbrella company.

I would like help to plan management of the umbrella company's domain name and how to properly feature the subsidiaries' websites (subdomains of umbrellacorp.com - subfolders or separate domains?) and how to deploy Google Apps for Business for all employees.

What is the best practice regarding email addresses?

Use full names or work titles?

Subdomains?

The companies are not internet savvy startups, they are more conventional with B2B word-of-mouth corporate clients. Hence a full blown website and branded email addresses for every company/employee is not so important, a simple information page on the umbrella website would do.

Suggestions:

`www.umbrellacorp.com` with emails:
`steve.stevenson@umbrellacorp.com` OR
`ceo@umbrellacorp.com`

`constructioncorp.umbrellacorp.com` with emails:
`john@constructioncorp.umbrellacorp.com`

`www.umbrellacorp.com/constructioncorp` with emails:
`john@constructioncorp.umbrellacorp.com` OR
`john@umbrellacorp.com`

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use fullname@company (or, more likely, first.lastname@) for everyone. I would possibly add aliases for the work titles where applicable. I would separate each company's employees to their own domain address. e.g.: john.doe@umbrellacorp.com, jane.smith@constructioncorp.com.

Comment: Thanks for your thought. I like the idea of first.last@umbrellacorp.com too, and I just learned about aliases yesterday too. Aliases seem great as I can add secretary@umbrellcorp.com and it goes to first.last if I want to. That way it hides their full name as well. Was that how you thought about that?

Comment: Followup-question. What if the secretary (first.name) quits after two years and there is a new-hire (new.name) who takes over the alias (secretary)? Do we transition all the first.name emails to new.name?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're asking what to do with new emails sent to the old secretary's address. I'm not sure, but I think you should forward emails from the old secretary's address to the new one, at least temporarily. You can achieve this by keeping the account active with a filter to forward all mail, or by deleting/changing the account's address and adding it as an alias to the new secretary's address.

Comment: Got it, well explained. When the old secretary quits I would go through and forward or migrate relevant secretary emails to the new secretary's email inbox and indeed redirect the secretary@umbrallcorp.com alias to new.secr@umbrellacorp.com?

Answer (score -1):

deployment plan outlines the scope, approach and execution planned for the deployment of the project deliverables(google apps email and business domain.)

First of all you need to find input and outputs.

**Inputs**:

What information needs to be gathered to create a deployment plan?
Deployment goals and critical success factors

Roles and responsibilities of the parties involved in the deployment of the project deliverables

-Task and resource dependencies

-How team members will communicate

-How to track issues and resolve them

-Contingency information

-Training plan

**Outputs:**

-Outcomes(Release Plan,Issue/Change Request Tracking Method,etc)

-Description

-Sample/Templates

**Steps:**

-Identify the resources required to support this product, including facilities, hardware, software, associated documentation, staff, etc.

-Describe any procedures or lessons learned that may help with the support.

-Describe any expected areas of change to the product.

-Describe the plans for transitioning the product to the support organization. 
  Include:

Roles and responsiblities for each activity

Resources needed to carry out the transition activities and where those resources will    come from

Schedule and milestones for conducting the transition

Installation procedures and other information necessary to support

Also Refer to **[how to deploy best strategic plans](http://www.bia.ca/articles/how-to-deploy-best-strategic-plan.htm)**

Comment: I appreciate your thought to help me answer my questions, but honestly, this copy/paste approach is really not helpful.